# project data for custom extension is not getting imported during junit init in hybris

Tags: java, junit, ant, sap-commerce-cloud, impex

Trying to import data for unit+integration tests at once (during init)
Running project update from HAC is working fine.

But when I use command to init or update project data for my custom or even for OOTB extension, it is not getting imported.

I have tried using following method for setup to import data :

```
@SystemSetup(type = Type.PROJECT, process = Process.ALL)
public void createProjectData(final SystemSetupContext context) {//...}
```

And I have tried "type = Type.ESSENTIAL" too for my impex import but not a success from CLI at platform directory.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: what command are you trying? did you use -Dtenant=junit with your ant command? Please provide some details

Comment: Have you declared your setup class as a Spring bean ?

Comment: yes, I have already created bean for my setup class and i am using command : "ant initialize -Dtenant=junit" for init process.

Comment: Can you show us, what you are exactly try to do? So show us the code plz

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is directly do it from your test code.
I give you an example in groovy :

```
def init(){

    //Call below line only if you want to do an init between two tests for example
    initTestTenant();

    //Call this to execute the code in createProjectData
    final SystemSetupContext systemSetupContext = new SystemSetupContext(new HashMap<String, String[]>(), Type.ESSENTIAL,
        Process.ALL, "projectname");
    yourExtensionSystemSetup.createProjectData(systemSetupContext);

}
```